# Pagination for posts inside a specific category

Tags: posts, pagination

I have a FAQ category and there are posts in that category I want to add pagination to that category only, not the other category in my wordpress.

In short giving pagination to selected category for the posts in that category

Comment: Could you rephrase this? Is this page a custom post template showing posts in a category or custom post type?  It's not clear what your asking

Comment: So? whats your question? I don't see any problem having that. Are you asking how to do pagination?

Comment: Actually its post type page and in a FAQ category i want to give pagination to that FAQ category

Comment: oooooh you should have said category, a page is a different thing in wordpress, they are not the same

Answer (score 1):

Create a `category-faq.php` in your theme folder ( assuming category is your taxonomy and faq is the term slug ), and put your category code in there, and add pagination code to that file. This is a category specific template.

For a view of what templates you can add and the types of instances they occur in and their fallbacks, refer to this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest usting custom templates for this; a good tutorial can be found here: http://www.vooshthemes.com/blog/wordpress-tip/create-a-professional-portfolio-using-wordpress-3-0-custom-post-types/

If you don't go the custom templates route you're going to need to create a template for that specific category - as mentioned above name it category-name.php... "name" should be replaced with the name of your category.

You can do the pagination with this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/

Alternatively, you can used WP's built-in pagination function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links